# Using PMU to count ticks on ARM

Tags: arm

I'm trying to use the PMU (specifically use `PMCCNTR` to determine ticks per usec) from userspace in ARM.  I have an arm64 kernel running an arm32 bit userspace app.

I created an LKM to force the `PMUSERENR.EN` bit to be on, which works.  I then I ran a test program from userspace:

```
asm volatile ("mrc p15, 0, %[en], c9, c14, 0" 
      : [en] "=r" (pmuserenr));
printf(" -- %08x\n", pmuserenr);
```

The first few times I ran this, the bit was correctly marked as turned on.  But every third or fourth time I run it, the bit shows up as off.   After puzzling over this, I came across [this link](https://lists.linaro.org/pipermail/lng-odp/2014-October/004001.html), where the user is enabling this bit for each cpu.   Does each core have it's own instance of a PMU, or is there only one per SoC?   If there are multiple per SoC, are the `PMUCCNTR` registers synced up?  (That is, if I read the `PMUCCNTR`, then do a context switch to another core, and read `PMUCCNTR` again, can I safely compare the two to see how many ticks have elapsed?).

Even if I modify my LKM to initialize on every online-cpu (and register a notifier to enable it on all new cpu's coming up), I'm still seeing the same behavior, where every nth read from userspace shows the bit not set.

My other issue is that the `PMCCNTR` is not incrementing.   I set the `PMCR.E` bit but it's still not incrementing.   I found one website that says I need to set the `PMCR.C` bit -- but this has a side effect of clearing the counter, which I don't want to do in fear of creating a race condition (where someone else is using the counter as I clear it).    Any help or insights would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each cpu has its own PMU instance, they are entirely independant (except for a small number of cluster wide events, where each PMU keeps its own count).

See, for example, the first hit today for ["debug memory map pmu"](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0500e/BABEAFAG.html), remembering that v7 and v8 debug memory map standards are different. The actual answer is too 'obvious' to expect it to be explicitly documented.

> ```
> 0x010000 - 0x010FFF   CPU 0 Debug
> 0x030000 - 0x030FFF   CPU 0 PMU
> 0x110000 - 0x110FFF   CPU 1 Debug
> 0x130000 - 0x130FFF   CPU 1 PMU
> 0x210000 - 0x210FFF   CPU 2 Debug
> 0x230000 - 0x230FFF   CPU 2 PMU
> 0x310000 - 0x310FFF   CPU 3 Debug
> 0x330000 - 0x330FFF   CPU 3 PMU
> ```

Comment: Thanks.  I noticed you work for ARM, so I'll take it you know what you're talking about.    Are there any registers that can be read that would give a core-independent tick count?

Comment: Indeed - at least when it comes to hardware. I suspect this may be one of the details which is only implicitly documented (e.g. in the cluster external debug memory map). I can't think of any need for a free running counter in the cluster which is not the global timer (at lower resolution).

Comment: I wouldn't consider this obvious -- I wouldn't have thought to look in the 'extern debug memory map' section of the document, and several references to PMU from third party sources led me to the wrong conclusion (meaning I wasn't the only one with this misconception).   If you work for Arm, you might mention to your documentation team to explicitly mention this in the PMU section (perhaps in 'About the Performance Monitors' section).   Thanks for mentioning global timers, I'm just looking into those now as an alternative.